# How to use $dateFromString in Spring MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

In my document, the date field is a string `"date": "01/08/2018"`. How can I convert it to Date object in Spring MongoDB to able to use comparator operators like "gte, lte" to other date object.

I tried:

```
project()

   .and(DateOperators.DateFromString.fromStringOf("date")).as("date")
```

It just works with fields whose format is `yyyy-MM-dd`, and of course I ended up with:

```
'Error parsing date string '26/10/2016'; 0: Unexpected character '2'
```

How can I pass the pattern or Is there another way to get the my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `format` option has been added to `$dateFromString` in MongoDB Version 4 and is currently missing in Spring Data MongoDB. I've opened [DATAMONGO-2047](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2047) to address the issue.
Meanwhile you may try the following to add it manually.

```java
project().and(context -> {

    Document doc = DateFromString.fromStringOf("date").toDocument(context);
    doc.get("$dateFromString", Document.class).put("format", "dd/mm/yyyy");
    return doc;
}).as("date");
```